# How to interlock shapes in Java

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have a project where I have to draw Olympic Rings and I am having trouble making it seem like the ring interlock. This is a picture that shows what I mean.

[image]

notice how they interlock? That's what I want right now I only have the shapes sitting on top of each other. This is what I have right now.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color; //sets color
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;

class ColoredOlypmicRings extends JFrame {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        float strokeThickness = 27.0f;
        float arcThickness = 9.0f;
        BasicStroke Outline = new BasicStroke(strokeThickness);
        BasicStroke arcOutline = new BasicStroke(arcThickness);
        g2d.setStroke(Outline);
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.drawOval(100, 100, 300, 300);
        g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2d.drawOval(265, 300, 300, 300);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.drawOval(430, 100, 300, 300);
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.drawOval(595, 300, 300, 300);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.drawOval(760, 100, 300, 300);
        g2d.setStroke(arcOutline);
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawArc(253, 378, 50, 75, -230, 58); // -270 start
        g2d.drawArc(290, 370, 50, 75, -230, 58);
        g2d.drawArc(360, 285, 50, 75, -230, 58);
        g2d.drawArc(405, 285, 50, 75, -230, 58);

    }

    public ColoredOlypmicRings() {
        setSize(1200, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColoredOlypmicRings guiWindow = new ColoredOlypmicRings();
        guiWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hang on for example.....

Answer (score 5):

1. Draw arcs of colors that when combined form your circles rather than drawing whole ovals.
2. The top layer of arcs need to be drawn last. This may take a little trial and error, but you can do this.
3. General recommendation to never draw in a top level window such as a JFrame.
4. Instead draw within a JPanel's paintComponent method, and then display that JPanel within your JFrame
5. Always call the super's painting method in your overridden method.
6. Smooth your drawing by using Graphics2D setRenderingHints and turn anti-aliasing *on*.

First iteration -- not yet fully fixed:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OlympicRings extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.WHITE;
    private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int OVAL_HEIGHT = OVAL_WIDTH;
    private static final int X_START = 100;
    private static final int Y_START = X_START;
    private static final int DELTA_X = 175;
    private static final int DELTA_Y = 180;
    private static final Color COLOR_GOLD = new Color(242, 205, 25);
    private static final Stroke INNER_STROKE = new BasicStroke(30f);
    private static final Stroke OUTER_STROKE = new BasicStroke(40f);
    private static final int ARC_LENGTH = 30;
    private static final int CIRCLE_DEGREES = 360;

    public OlympicRings() {
        setBackground(BG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int x = X_START;
        int y = Y_START;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLUE, OVAL_WIDTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, COLOR_GOLD, OVAL_WIDTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLACK, OVAL_WIDTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.GREEN.darker(), OVAL_WIDTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.RED, OVAL_WIDTH);

        x = X_START;
        y = Y_START;
        int angle = CIRCLE_DEGREES - ARC_LENGTH;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLUE, OVAL_WIDTH, angle, ARC_LENGTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, COLOR_GOLD, OVAL_WIDTH, 0, ARC_LENGTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLACK, OVAL_WIDTH, angle, ARC_LENGTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.GREEN.darker(), OVAL_WIDTH, 0, ARC_LENGTH);        

        g2.dispose();        
    }

    private void myDrawArc(Graphics2D g2, Stroke innerStroke, Stroke outerStroke, int x, int y,
            Color bg2, Color color, int ovalWidth, int start, int end) {
        g2.setStroke(outerStroke);
        g2.setColor(bg2);
        g2.drawArc(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth, start, end);

        g2.setStroke(innerStroke);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.drawArc(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth, start, end);        
    }

    private void myDrawOval(Graphics2D g2, Stroke innerStroke, Stroke outerStroke, int x, int y,
            Color bg2, Color color, int ovalWidth) {
        g2.setStroke(outerStroke);
        g2.setColor(bg2);
        g2.drawOval(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth);

        g2.setStroke(innerStroke);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.drawOval(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = 2 * X_START + DELTA_X * 4 + OVAL_WIDTH;
        int h = 2 * Y_START + DELTA_Y + OVAL_HEIGHT;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        OlympicRings mainPanel = new OlympicRings();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OlympicRings");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

This is not quite there as my background stroke extends beyond the end of the arc:

[image]

still working on it.

Slightly better:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OlympicRings extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.WHITE;
    private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int OVAL_HEIGHT = OVAL_WIDTH;
    private static final int X_START = 100;
    private static final int Y_START = X_START;
    private static final int DELTA_X = 175;
    private static final int DELTA_Y = 180;
    private static final Color COLOR_GOLD = new Color(242, 205, 25);
    private static final Stroke INNER_STROKE = new BasicStroke(30f, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    private static final Stroke OUTER_STROKE = new BasicStroke(40f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    private static final int ARC_LENGTH = 30;
    private static final int CIRCLE_DEGREES = 360;

    public OlympicRings() {
        setBackground(BG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int x = X_START;
        int y = Y_START;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLUE, OVAL_WIDTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, COLOR_GOLD, OVAL_WIDTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLACK, OVAL_WIDTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.GREEN.darker(), OVAL_WIDTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawOval(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.RED, OVAL_WIDTH);

        x = X_START;
        y = Y_START;
        int angle = CIRCLE_DEGREES - ARC_LENGTH;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLUE, OVAL_WIDTH, angle, ARC_LENGTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, COLOR_GOLD, OVAL_WIDTH, 0, ARC_LENGTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLACK, OVAL_WIDTH, angle, ARC_LENGTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.GREEN.darker(), OVAL_WIDTH, 0, ARC_LENGTH);        

        g2.dispose();        
    }

    private void myDrawArc(Graphics2D g2, Stroke innerStroke, Stroke outerStroke, int x, int y,
            Color bg2, Color color, int ovalWidth, int start, int end) {
        g2.setStroke(outerStroke);
        g2.setColor(bg2);
        g2.drawArc(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth, start, end);

        g2.setStroke(innerStroke);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.drawArc(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth, start, end);        
    }

    private void myDrawOval(Graphics2D g2, Stroke innerStroke, Stroke outerStroke, int x, int y,
            Color bg2, Color color, int ovalWidth) {
        g2.setStroke(outerStroke);
        g2.setColor(bg2);
        g2.drawOval(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth);

        g2.setStroke(innerStroke);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.drawOval(x, y, ovalWidth, ovalWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = 2 * X_START + DELTA_X * 4 + OVAL_WIDTH;
        int h = 2 * Y_START + DELTA_Y + OVAL_HEIGHT;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        OlympicRings mainPanel = new OlympicRings();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OlympicRings");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Latest change:

```
        x = X_START;
        y = Y_START;
        int angle = CIRCLE_DEGREES - ARC_LENGTH;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLUE, OVAL_WIDTH, angle, ARC_LENGTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, COLOR_GOLD, OVAL_WIDTH, 57, ARC_LENGTH);
        x += DELTA_X;
        y -= DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.BLACK, OVAL_WIDTH, angle, ARC_LENGTH);        
        x += DELTA_X;
        y += DELTA_Y;
        myDrawArc(g2, INNER_STROKE, OUTER_STROKE, x, y, BG, Color.GREEN.darker(), OVAL_WIDTH, 57, ARC_LENGTH);
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the output of the code that the OP posted:
[image: Output of OP's code]

**White border around rings** - instead of attempting to hard-code the border only when rings cross each other, you should draw a white arc before you draw any color arc, with the white arc having a broader stroke than the colored one.

**Overlaps** - if you draw all rings one after the other, you will have to fix at least 4 overlaps so that it looks like the logo you're after. You should repaint each of those 4 overlaps (blue-over-yellow, yellow-over-black, black-over-green, green-over-red) by redrawing only the corresponding arc portion.

**Colors & distances** - use a color-picker tool to find the exact RGB values of the colors you are after from those in your sample image. You should also space your rings out horizontally a bit more, and draw the top row closer to the bottom row.

---

Edit: following my own advice, here's my output

[image: olympic logo]

And the program to generate it (import statements ommitted)

```
public static void paintRing(Graphics2D g, BasicStroke bs, BasicStroke fs, 
        double x, double y, 
        double r, double rw, Color color, int a0, int a) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float)rw*1.5f));
    g.drawArc((int)x, (int)y, (int)r, (int)r, a0+5, a-10);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float)rw));
    g.drawArc((int)x, (int)y, (int)r, (int)r, a0, a);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    rh.put( RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

    double w = getWidth();

    // eyeballed measurements
    double m = w/12;
    double dx = w/7;
    double dy = w/8;
    double x = m;
    double y = .7 * m;
    double r = w/4;

    // for partial lines
    int fwdStart = -30;
    int topStart = 90-30;

    // background & foreground strokes
    float rw = (float)w/40;
    BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(rw*1.5f);
    BasicStroke fs = new BasicStroke(rw);

    // colors
    Color blue = new Color(0, 133, 199);
    Color gold = new Color(244, 195, 0);
    Color black = Color.black;
    Color green = new Color(0, 159, 61);
    Color red = new Color(223, 0, 36);

    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x, y, r, rw, blue, 0, 360);
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+dx, y+dy, r, rw, gold, 0, 360);        
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+2*dx, y, r, rw, black, 0, 360);

    // mesh blue-gold-black
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+dx, y+dy, r, rw, gold, topStart, 60);
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x, y, r, rw, blue, fwdStart, 60);

    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+3*dx, y+dy, r, rw, green, 0, 360);
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+4*dx, y, r, rw, red, 0, 360);

    // mesh red-green-black
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+3*dx, y+dy, r, rw, green, topStart, 60);
    paintRing(g2d, fs, bs, x+2*dx, y, r, rw, black, fwdStart, 60);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(new Olympic());
    jf.setSize(800, 400);
    jf.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: The arcs on the topside of the yellow circle are wrong

Comment: That's the code that the OP posted - I just display it in my answer to comment on it